# echo from lines of a file

Tags: bash, echo, cat

i have a file "myfile.txt" that have the next content:

```
hola mundo
hello word
```

and i want work with every line

```
for i in `cat myfile.txt`; do echo $i; done
```

i hope this give me

```
hola mundo
hello word
```

firts one line, then the other, but get

```
hola
mundo
hello
word
```

as I can demanding results until newline instead of each space?

ty all

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's better

```
cat myfile.txt | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

or even better (doesn't launch other processes such as a subshell and `cat`):

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done < myfile.txt
```

If you prefer oneliners, it's obviously

```
while read line; do echo "$line"; done < myfile.txt
```

Comment: In the second version, why do you add the file name in the end and how does it work? especially the last line `done < myfile.txt`